# switching FileAppenders on the fly

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I've got a legacy logging class.  Its got a static Logger reference (named logger) and a bunch of static methods.

Each method takes a String input and writes it to System.out.println and to logger if logger is not null.

Its got a constructor that initializes logger.  But this constructor only has package scope and I'm pretty sure its not being called anywhere.  Therefore logger is always null and the class essentially only ever executes System.out.println

I want to change this so it can be used in a multi threaded application where each thread writes to its own unique FileAppender.

And that's where I'm stuck.

Basically, what I want to do is have this static class associated with a bunch of different log4j FileAppenders.  Each FileAppender can be created by the Thread, and the file name can be derived from unique information known to the Thread.

What I can't figure out how to do is magically use Log4j to communicate that Thread's unique FileAppender to this legacy logging class.

Ideas?  Hints?  Suggestions?

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to change the target log file name dynamically using a RoutingAppender and the ThreadContext map.

This can all be done with configuration (no need for custom code where threads create FileAppenders). In the RoutingAppender configuration you can specify a ThreadContext key you want to use to switch the target FileAppender. For example, you can use the string "ROUTINGKEY". Each thread puts a unique value in the ThreadContext map for key "ROUTINGKEY", and this value is used to select the Appender that the log event is routed to. You can even set it up to dynamically create log files that have the ROUTINGKEY value in the file name, so not all target log files need to be known in advance.

The FAQ page has a good example: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files